# All requests go into ELB surge queue

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

A problem: It seems like every single request to our application ends up in ELB surge queue

Example of a surge queue chart:
[image]

We have a classic ELB on AWS with multiple EC2 boxes behind it. ELB listeners setup in a next way

```
LB Protocol  LB Port  Instance Protocol  Instance Port  Cipher SSL  Certificate 
TCP          80       TCP                80              N/A        N/A
```

On an EC2 instance we have an nginx server with next nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 3;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
worker_rlimit_sigpending 32768;

events {
  worker_connections 2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
  accept_mutex off;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  map_hash_bucket_size 128;
  server_tokens off;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $request_time';

  access_log /app/log/nginx/access.log main;
  error_log /app/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  client_body_temp_path /app/tmp/nginx;:q

  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  upstream tomcat {
    server localhost:8080;
  }

  upstream httpd {
    server localhost:9000;
  }

  upstream play {
    server localhost:9000;
  }
```

and vhost sites.conf

```
log_format  proxylog  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$proxy_protocol_addr" $request_time';

server { 
  server_name     www.my-site.com;
  rewrite ^(.*)   http://my-site.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80 proxy_protocol;

  listen 443 ssl proxy_protocol;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/my-certificate.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/my-key.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "SECRET";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
  root /app/websites/my-site.com/httpdocs;
  index index.html index.htm;
  real_ip_header proxy_protocol;

  server_name my-site.com;
  access_log /app/log/nginx/my-site.com.access.log proxylog buffer=16k flush=2s;
  error_log /app/log/nginx/my-site.com.error.log;

  charset utf-8;

  location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://play;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location /bar {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, User-Agent, Authorization, Referer, Timestamp' always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
    proxy_pass http://play;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

  location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, User-Agent, Authorization, Referer, Timestamp' always;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;

    real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;

    proxy_read_timeout 90s;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_pass  http://play;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

  }

  location ~ ^/(images|css|js|html) {
    root /app/websites/my-site.com/httpdocs;
  }

  error_page  404              /404.html;

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

I'm limiting possible suspects of a problem to ELB and nginx, and not the most obvious – actual web server processing requests, because in one of my tests I completely removed java application, and replaces it with a dummy node.js server which was replying 'hello world' to every request, and I was still getting all those requests logged in surge queue.

I also tried adjusting `worker_processes` and `keepalive_timeout` to see if it affects anything, and it doesn't.

What bothers me, is that this surge queue of 1 doesn't affect performance of a service, as it seems like requests tend to stay there fractions of seconds, but what I don't understand is why even a single request ends up passing through surge queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have your ELB set to TCP?

If so, your ELB will register every connection made into the surge queue. There is no getting around that I'm afraid. You have to use http or https to get surge queue working properly.

--

**Update from OP**

I created a tiny EC2 instance, with a simple TCP server which just replies 'potato' to every request. I put it behind a classic ELB with TCP listener, and a made a single request to my fresh ELB, and checked surge queue chart.

[image]

Looking at AWS documentation [Listeners for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html)

> When you use TCP (layer 4) for both front-end and back-end
>   connections, your load balancer forwards the request to the back-end
>   instances without modifying the headers. After your load balancer
>   receives the request, it attempts to open a TCP connection to the
>   back-end instance on the port specified in the listener configuration.

and this:

> For every registered and healthy instance behind an HTTP/HTTPS load
>   balancer, Elastic Load Balancing opens and maintains one or more TCP
>   connections. These connections ensure that there is always an
>   established connection ready to receive HTTP/HTTPS requests.

Which from my understanding implies that every time we make a call to TCP configured ELB, it set our request aside, to be able to open a connection to our EC2, and only then passes request to machine.

Comment: Yes TCP. Do you know any source that explains this?

Comment: Honestly, I don't have a source for you @igormilla, but I remember doing a boat load of research on it when I set mine up as I was going to scale based on surge queue length too, and found a single document somewhere that explained that this was the case. It also correlated with exactly what I was seeing. :)

Comment: I just checked all our other ELBs we have and it does seem to correlate with it too. I will do some more testing here and will come back later with some results, and your deserved 'accept'

Comment: You were right! I'm updating your answer with some of my finding.

Comment: @igormilla - approved. Thanks for the edit! :) Have fun.

Comment: "I created a tiny EC2 instance, with a simple TCP server which just replies 'potato' to every request." I really, really love this.